# Using LiveData as state inside Jetpack @Compose functions

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I want to use a `LiveData<List<DataClass>>` to be the source of my state in a @Composable function.

I cannot use the new @Model annotation, I have seen in this talk [Link(at 32:06)](https://youtu.be/dtm2h-_sNDQ?t=1926) it is possible to use LiveData, Flow, etc. by invoking the function `+observe(/* Data */)`.

To the problem:
I cannot find the function used in the video (+observe()) or any other way to use LiveData as an origin. 
How can I use LiveData inside my @Compose function?

Project Gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.60-eap-76'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0-alpha04'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

App gradle: Dependencies:

```
   def lifecycle_version = "2.1.0"
   def compose_version = "0.1.0-dev02"

    // ViewModel and LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$lifecycle_version"

    implementation "androidx.compose:compose-runtime:$compose_version"
    kapt "androidx.compose:compose-compiler:$compose_version"

    // Android Compose
    implementation "androidx.ui:ui-layout:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.ui:ui-foundation:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.ui:ui-framework:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.ui:ui-android-text:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.ui:ui-text:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.ui:ui-material:$compose_version"
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Here is another way to observe live data using state. There is an extension function for this just include it.

add gradle dependency below one:

```
implementation 'androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.0.0-beta01'
```

now just convert your regular **LiveData to State** for example.

```
 val breedItems by doggoViewModel.liveBreedData().observeAsState()
```

Comment: How do we access `viewLifecycleOwner` in side of a Composable?

Answer (score 22):

As some already pointed out you need to add the new dependency to build.gradle

`implementation 'androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.0.0-beta01'`

And then simply:

```
val name: String by viewModel.name.observeAsState("")
```

If this does not work for you try the next below. The above syntax is clearly the better one and is also recommended but did not work for me.

```
val nameState: State<String> = viewModel.name.observeAsState("")
nameState.value
```

See also the documentation about state here https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#viewmodel-state

Comment: Actually, `viewModel.name.observeAsState()` returns `State<String>` and `viewModel.name.observeAsState("")` returns `String`.

Comment: Use 1.2.0-beta01

Answer (score 11):

[0.1.0-dev09](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/ui#0.1.0-dev09) now includes `ui-livedata`. Example use [here](https://github.com/vinaygaba/Learn-Jetpack-Compose-By-Example/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetpackcompose/state/livedata/LiveDataActivity.kt).

Comment: for compose beta, it's now `implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:$compose_version"`

Answer (score 6):

The `+observe` method is not available yet but it(or something similar) should be available in a future release of Jetpack Compose.

If you'd like to use a similar functionality before its officially released, you can use this function that I found in this blog post - https://medium.com/swlh/android-mvi-with-jetpack-compose-b0890f5156ac

Posting below for easier consumption

```
fun <T> observe(data: LiveData<T>) = effectOf<T?> {
    val result = +state<T?> { data.value }
    val observer = +memo { Observer<T> { result.value = it } }

    +onCommit(data) {
        data.observeForever(observer)
        onDispose { data.removeObserver(observer) }
    }

    result.value
}
```

**Update** The unary(+) operator and effectOf have been deprecated as of 0.1.0-dev05. Also `memo` has been renamed to `remember` Here is what you should use instead -

```
@Composable
fun <T> observe(data: LiveData<T>): T? {
    var result by state { data.value }
    val observer = remember { Observer<T> { result = it } }

    onCommit(data) {
        data.observeForever(observer)
        onDispose { data.removeObserver(observer) }
    }

    return result
}
```

Source - https://kotlinlang.slack.com/archives/CJLTWPH7S/p1581276282423600?thread_ts=1581276282.423600

Comment: Looks like use of `effectOf` in dev05 release gives an error.  Any idea what recommended approach now is?

Comment: I accepted the other answer for the 0.1.0-dev09 usage.