# How to observe livedata in compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I need to observe change in list which I am fetching from firebase

```
viewModel.courseList.observe(viewLifeCycleOwner,{

})
```

But I'm not able to use `viewLifeCycleOwner`.

Comment: What do you mean "not able to use"?

Comment: You get some error logs? Why not just use `observeAsState`?

Comment: add more detail please

Comment: I am fetching the list from firebase in another function but somehow my UI is not updating

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using LiveData as state inside Jetpack @Compose functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59096435/using-livedata-as-state-inside-jetpack-compose-functions)

Answer (score 5):

```
class MyViewModel: ViewModel() {
    private var _courseList = MutableLiveData<Whatever>()
    var courseList: LiveData<List<Whatever>> = _courseList
}

@Composable
fun MyComposable() {
    val list  = myViewModel.courseList.observeAsState().value
}
```

Demo app has plenty of examples:
https://github.com/JohannBlake/Jetmagic

Comment: You'll need to add a compose dependency for observeAsState():  androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata

Comment: Thanks  a lot, you repo helps me with a big problem